# Problem with fullscreen OpenGL on the Mac

Tags: cocoa, macos, opengl, fullscreen

Now I am porting some OpenGL tutorials from win/glut to cocoa/mac os x. In the windowed mode everything works, but when context switches to fullscreen, screen may be empty (only clear colour)! For example: in the first, second, third times cube is, but in the fourth time cube is not. Even if app launches in fullscreen without sharing context. I don`t understand.

Xcode 3.2.1, Mac OS X 10.6.2

[source link](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/117417/mac.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AFController's `enterFullScreen` method probably needs to set up the OpenGL context (`[scene initGL]`).

Also, `awakeFromNib` may be called before the application is ready to draw, so perhaps it's not the best place for `[scene initGL]`. I suggest implementing NSApplication's delegate method, `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, and moving `[scene initGL]` there. Just to be safe, you might also try calling NSOpenGLContext's `makeCurrentContext` from there as well.

Comment: I fixed bits of code that you said, but nothing changes. I test app under both 10.6 and 10.5